# Create a file outside of Docker container while container is running in Python

Tags: python, docker

I currently have a Python application running in a Docker container on Ubuntu 20.04.

In this Python application I want to create a text file every few minutes for use in other applications on the Ubuntu server. However, I am finding it challenging to create a file and save it on the server from inside a containerised Python application.

The application Dockerfile/start.sh/main.py files reside in /var/www/my_app_name/ and I would like to have the output.txt file that main.py creates in that same folder, the location of the Dockerfile/main.py source.

The text file is created in Python using a simple line:

```
text_file = open("my_text_file.txt", "wt")
```

I have seen that the best way to do this is to use a volume. My current `docker run` which is called by batch script `start.sh` includes the line:

```
docker run -d --name=${app} -v $PWD:/app ${app}
```

However I am not having much luck and the file is not created in the working directory where main.py resides.

Comment: Since your Ubuntu system should come with Python preinstalled, you should just be able to run the `main.py` script without involving Docker.  That will be able to directly write the host filesystem, without any special setup.

Answer (score 0):

A bind mount is the way to go and your `-v $PWD:/app` should work.

If you run a command like

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/app alpine /bin/sh -c 'echo Hello > /app/hello.txt'
```

you'll get a file in your current directory called `hello.txt`.

The command runs an Alpine image, maps the current directory to `/app` in the container and then echoes 'Hello' to `/app/hello.txt` in the container.

Comment: Thanks for the response Hans, I've tried your `docker run` command provided and it does indeed work, so it's odd that my command in the initial question doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this myself, thanks to those who answered to get me on the right path.

For those finding this question in the future, creating a bind mound using the `-v` flag in `docker run` is indeed the correct way to go, just ensure that you have the correct path.

To get the file `my_text_file.txt` in the folder where my `main.py` and `Dockerfile` files are located, I changed my above to:

```
-v $PWD:/src/output ${app}
```

The `/src/output` is a folder structure within the container where `my_text_file.txt` is created, so in the Python, you should be saving the file using:

```
text_file = open("/src/output/my_text_file.txt", "wt")
```

The `${PWD}` is where the `my_text_file.txt` is located on the local machine.

In short, I was not saving my file to the correct folder within the container in the Python code, it should have been saved to `app` in the container, and then my solution in the OP would have worked.